# My minecraft PE textures are not loading right and turning black how do I fix it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm not using any texture packs or anything like that. Here is a screenshot of the game.[image]

Comment: If they were actually gone, the textures would be purple and black squares. Is it still there after you've restarted the game?

Comment: yea, I'm not quite sure whats happening